# correct way to handle timeout in CompletableFuture.allof and logging the timed out futures

Tags: java, java-8, completable-future

I've ItemDetails and ItemPriceDetails defined as below -

```
class ItemDetails {
  private int itemId;
  private int uom;
  private int zipcode;
  private String promoCode;
}

class ItemPriceDetails {
  private int itemId;
  private int uom;
  private int zipcode;
  private float totalCost;
  private float totalTax;
  private TaxDetails taxDetails;
  private DiscountDetails discountDetails;
}
```

`InventoryTargetExecutors` is third party jar which provides `fetchPrice` functions which takes `ItemDetails` as input and returns `CompletableFuture<ItemPriceDetails>` as output.

I want to call multiple InventoryTargetExecutors in parallel using `CompletableFuture.allof` function with specified timeout and print the `InventoryTargetExecutors` that are timedout during the invocation.

```
ItemDetails  ids = ...;
List<InventoryConfigExecutors> inventoryConfigExecutors = applicationContext.get("InventoryConfigExecutors");
List<CompletableFuture<Pair<ItemPriceDetails, InventoryConfigExecutors>>> priceFutures =  inventoryConfigExecutors.stream().map(ice -> Pair.of(ice.fetchPrice(ids), ice)).collect(Collectors.toList());
CompletableFuture<Void> futuresExecuted = CompletableFuture.allOf(priceFutures.toArray(new CompletableFuture[priceFutures.size()]));
```

I don't know how to timeout the the priceFutures using CompletableFuture.allof  and at the same time log the InventoryConfigExecutors that are timed out.

Comment: How do you want to handle a timeout in **any** of the tasks?

Comment: timeout will be Long value (around 200ms) configured in ApplicationContext.xml file. If any one of the future takes more than configured time period to return the value then I want to log the `InventoryExecutorId` value of the InventoryConfigExecutors class.

Answer (score 1):

If using JDK 9 or higher, `CompletableFuture.orTimeout` will allow you to set the timeout.
For earlier versions, you need to implement that yourself, possibly by scheduling a task that calls `completeExceptionally`.

For logging, you can use `whenComplete` and check the throwable argument, logging if it’s present.
**Note:** this does not distinguish between timeouts or other failures.